# How to install Visual Studio Code Editor on latest Raspbian Stretch 2018?

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have followed many guides that include these:-
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Yet, I am not successful. I follwed the installation guide for ubuntu, sice Ubuntu and Raspbian are similar. Could you please help me.

Thanks :)

Regards,
Jonathan Gerard Joseph J

Comment: There seem to be several guides.  Could you list the ones you have tried so we don't waste our time.

Comment: Normally I would suggest using the builds by 'headmelted', but I think recent builds have some problems. https://code.headmelted.com/

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why and where does the guides fail? Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.